# Different screen height problem raised , MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / value wont work ? Flutter UI

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

In the picture below, I tried using the `SizedBox` Widget and I set the height:

```
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5.9,
),
```

[image]

The second solution is I try to use `LayoutBuilder` widget and builder and I specify the height: `constraints.maxHeight * 0.4` but I'm getting the same result.

Here's the code:

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildCoverImage(screenSize),

            SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5.9),
                      _buildProfileImage(),
                      _buildFullName(context),
                      _buildStatContainer(context),
                       
                    ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: my achieve is to fix the UI . the cover behind the circular image must be same height on different screen sizes ?

Comment: why do you need 2 `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Btw, why don't you use the `Positioned` widget inside `Stack`, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**output**

[image: outPut]

Hope you want something like this, while using `LayoutBuilder` use it at top level of widget tree.

**example code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BackSide extends StatelessWidget {
  const BackSide({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SizedBox(
          height: constraints.maxHeight,
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              // _buildCoverImage(screenSize),
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                child: Text("Background"),
              ),

              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * .4,
                    ),

                    ...List.generate(
                        15,
                        (index) => Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              color: index % 2 == 0
                                  ? Colors.pinkAccent
                                  : Colors.cyanAccent,
                              child: Text("item $index"),
                            )).toList(),
                    // _buildProfileImage(),
                    // _buildFullName(context),
                    // _buildStatContainer(context),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```